# Stack of elements

Tags: java, types, stack

How do I insert elements of different data types into a single stack in Java?

Answer (score 10):

It seems to defeat the purpose of [generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html), but here it goes:

```
Stack<Object>s = new Stack<Object>();
s.add("hello");
s.add(1);           // int is autoboxed to Integer
```

The catch will be that when retrieving the `Object`s from the `Stack`, it's going to take some effort to find out what type of each element is -- it will require using `instanceof` and typecasts:

```
while (!s.isEmpty()) {
  Object e = s.pop();

  if (e instanceof String)
    System.out.println("String: " + (String)e);
  else if (e instanceof Integer)
    System.out.println("Integer: " + (Integer)e);
  else
    System.out.println("Other type: " + e);
}
```

And now, we have something resembling the fragile code of the pre-Java 5 days before generics was added to the language.

Comment: The danger is when you retrieve the items later on, you have to write checks for object types.

Comment: Absolutely -- I just finished adding that part in as an edit.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, you'll want to solve this using inheritance. Possibly using a marker interface:

```
interface MyMarker
{
}

class Foo implements MyMarker
{
}

class Bar implements MyMarker
{
}
```

Interfaces are practical in cases like this, because you can implement an unlimited number of interfaces in a single class, and you can add extra interfaces anywhere in the class hierchy.

You can then put Foo and Bar in the same stack:

```
Stack<MyMarker> s = new Stack<MyMarker>();
s.add(new Foo());
s.add(new Bar());
```

This is the way to go if it's at all possible. Otherwise you'll have to do it like coobird suggests.

Comment: This is definitely a better way -- whenever there's a if-elseif ladder of "instanceof"s, the solution is usually inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The generic argument of the stack should be a common super type of all the element runtime types. For completely heterogeneous collections, `Object` is the common super type of all reference types. So:

```
Queue<Object> stack = Collections.asLifoQueue(new ArrayDeque<Object>());
stack.add("red");
stack.add(Color.GREEN);
stack.add(stack);
```

Obviously you when you come to pop those elements off the stack you will need to do `instanceof` checking to route to appropriate code (and probably cast).

Probably better is to introduce a layer of indirection. Instead of putting the objects on the queue directly, wrap them in a meaningful object. The `instanceof` checks can all be replace by calls to (virtual) methods that perform the operations you require. This is how polymorphism is supposed to be.